# How to create an instance of ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I'm trying to create an instance of `ImageIcon` according to the instructions here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

```
/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                           String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have the image in the same folder as the java class, but it returns "Couldn't find file: .....". What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class.getResource() is for accessing stuff via classloader, e.g. things in the same jar as your application.

To access a file from filesystem create URL from file, e.g. `new File(path).toURI().toURL();`

Comment: you should even be able to use new ImageIcon(path, description), as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: That works, but it really isn't the correct way for a Java program to load an icon that's part of the application.  Alda should be using Class.getResource, especially if the file is already in the same directory as the class.